# How many integer solutions does the equation $(4a^2 - 4a - 4)^2 + b = 2ab$ have

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, number-theory

I have tried everything that came to my mind but none worked.

How many integer solutions does the equation $$(4a^2 - 4a - 4)^2 + b = 2ab$$ have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y=\dfrac{(4x^2-4x-4)^2}{2x-1}$. Let $2x-1 = u \implies u^2-3 = 4x^2-4x-4 $

$\implies y = \dfrac{(u^2-3)^2}{u} \implies y = u^3 - 6u + \frac{9}{u} \implies u = -9,-3,-1,1,3,9 \implies x = -4,-1, 0, 1,2, 5$

Comment: Right approach, small error: $u^2-5=4x^2-4x-4$ yields $u=\pm25,\pm5,\pm1 \Rightarrow x=-12,-2,0,1,3,13$

Answer (score 1):

Time for a bit of factorization!

Note that:
$$(4a^2-4a-4)^2=(2a-1)b\iff b=\frac{(4a^2-4a-4)^2}{(2a-1)}\in\mathbb{Z}$$
We have now reduced the problem to finding the integral points of the following function.

Using polynomial division, we can further reduce the quotient on the RHS.
The rest should now be trivial.